# Html page as home page in wordpress hosting

Tags: php, html, wordpress, ftp

**What i have**

- I have a wordpress hosting website.
- Wordpress admin information.
- FTP details

**What i do**

- I have create html website and upload it in ftp.

**What i need to do?**

- I have to launch my wordpress hosting website using those html pages website uploaded in ftp.
- So please tell me how to set theme and configure my wp-admin dashbord so i can use my html pages as website.

**EDIT: Question is on Hold. But i get a working solution**

- Step 1) Open Ftp
- Step 2) Delete all files with folder like www public_html
- Step 3) make your default page as index.html
- Step 4) It will know work as a default website
- Step 5) Open Your website in browser now you can see your static html page there

Comment: do you know WordPress?

Comment: i am a nerd in wordpress.

Comment: You need to know some development in WordPress.Because when you want to add html page in WordPress then your css/image will not show properly and you need to convert all that link for WordPress usable.If you know some kind of WordPress then you can do it easily to make a template of these page and create a page with that template. Hope you understand my point. Thanks :)

Comment: i have basic knowledge of wordpress, like post new posts. add pages over there etc, please give some tutorial for creating template and then use my own html page using it.

Comment: Have many youtube tutorial about that.Please search it so that you can learn a lot.Searching is the best way to learn perfectly and more information also. It may help you : https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/

Comment: sorry youtube restriction in my office. ok let me search over google thnx for help

Comment: Every page is wordpress use different template based on they define in the theme so you need to define your own template for homepage inside your selected theme. For the reference use this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to set up your own Wordpress Theme. I suggest using one of the starter themes. I've had the most success with http://underscores.me/

The idea is to modify the underscores theme you just downloaded (which has almost nothing in it) so that, when you open a page in your WP website, it shows nothing at all (not even the title, menus, sidebar, nor the post content). The general guideline is this:

**1. Study the .php files in the underscores theme you just downloaded.** Try to modify the PHP code so that you end up with files that show nothing when loaded by WordPress but still work without an error. This is mainly your header.php and footer.php file, your page.php file, and post.php. I might be missing some, just check all of them.

**2. Embed your HTML code into the PHP files of your theme.** What's of interest to you is to embed your header and footer in header.php and footer.php. This will load your header and footer on any of your pages but leave the middle section (your content) blank.

**3. Create new pages from the WP Dashboard** so that they're loaded dynamically alongside your header and footer (and whatever else you added). When you create a page, just **copy your HTML content into the page's content** (make sure to tick the "Text" tab and not the "Visual" tab in the WP Editor). Your website will load just like your pure-HTML one did but dynamically and in a WP environment.

Hope that was helpful. I know this is not the cleanest way to do it. But you'll learn in the process.